# Android and &nbsp; in TextView

Tags: android, textview

is it possible to add `&nbsp;` in TextView? Has anyone achieved similar functionality?

I want to have non-breakable space in TextView.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

`TextView` respects the [Unicode no-break space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm) (`\u00A0`), which would be a simpler/lighter solution than HTML.

Comment: That works great. You can add that to xml or in java code. Work fine in java code, in xml I haven't tested to much, but it should do the job.

Comment: Neither \u0020 nor \u00A0 work. Neither by setting them in XML (not even in the preview in XML) nor by setting them in Java with setText(). Tried both with Android 4.1 and 4.2

Comment: \u00A0 worked for me on Nexus 4 with Android 4.4 using it in strings.xml

Comment: \u00A0 works fine for me to from API-8 to API-19. Example of using: <string name="Today">Today\u00A0</string>

Comment: That doesn't work in conjunction with comma. You get a line break just after comma in such cases

Comment: \u00A0 doesn't do the trick for me. It doesn't make a space, just joins the words - Android 4.4.4, 5.0, 5.1

Comment: `&#160;` is whitespace for android. too late maybe

Comment: In Kotlin, it works very well.  I replace all the empty spaces with this, and it will ellipsize from the last characters.  str.replace(" ", "\u00A0") yields, "Hello wor..." instead of "Hello..."

Answer (score 36):

**It is possible to use `&nbsp;` to have a readable solution.** Including `\u00A0` or `&#160;` or `&#xa0;`/`&#x00a0;` in the text doesn't really convey much information to the reader of the source code (or translator for that matter), unless you remember the hex codes. Here's a way to use the named entity in `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"><!-- non-breaking space, U+00A0 -->
]>
<resources>
    ...
</resources>
```

This will create the missing declaration. The original **HTML** declaration can be found in https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent referenced from the usual [XHTML DTDs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#dtds). All this works, because the XML parser reads these and substitutes while loading the file, so the entity won't be present in the resulting compiled resources.

## `&nbsp;` in Android Text (`CharSequence`) Resources

```
<!-- Defined in <resources> -->
<string name="html_text">Don\'t break <b>this&nbsp;name</b></string>

<!-- Used in a layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#10000000"
    android:text="@string/html_text"
    />
```

Device and preview (preview doesn't recognize HTML)
[image: HTML on device]
[image: HTML in preview]

## `&nbsp;` in Android String (formatted) Resources

```
<!-- Defined in <resources> -->
<string name="formatted_text">%1$s is&nbsp;nice</string>

<!-- Used in a layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#10000000"
    tools:text="@string/formatted_text"
    />
```

Then in code:

```
String contents = getString(R.string.formatted_text, "Using an &nbsp;");
((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(contents);
```

Device and preview (preview doesn't recognize entities and Java strings are literal text!)
[image: formatted on device]
[image: formatted in preview]

## Further tricks

These are just example uses of DTD entities, use it base on your own preference.

```
<!ENTITY con "\&apos;"><!-- contraction, otherwise error: "Apostrophe not preceded by \"
                            Sadly &apos; cannot be overridden due to XML spec:
                            https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent -->
<!ENTITY param1 "&#37;1$s"><!-- format string argument #1 -->

<string name="original">Don\'t wrap %1$s</string>
<string name="with_entities">Don&con;t wrap &param1;</string>
```

Both of them help highlighting:
[image: highlighted XML entities]

Comment: Android handles the `’` character just fine, no need to create apostrophe entities. `<string name="original">Don’t wrap %1$s</string>` works as expected.

Comment: @Diti That's not an [APOSTROPHE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm), that's a [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm); compare `'` VS `’`. Android has no problems with more fancy Unicode characters, but it has a problem with ASCII 0x27, which needs escaping. The entity is just a convenience, I just put it there to demonstrate where it could be useful.

Comment: This is excellent =) Thank you.  I find this much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I agree that having `&nbsp;` in the strings is way more meaningful to translators than the unicode `\u00A0`

Comment: Seems like the DOCTYPE declaration is working fine, but I need to add another Entity, how can I add two or more entities to the resources?

Comment: @Seven of course, see last section (Further tricks) which adds `con` and `param1` in the same file.

Answer (score 27):

`\u00A0` is a non-breaking space, `\u0020` is not a non-breaking space

Answer (score 23):

The TextView should respect the non breaking space

```
<string name="test">Hello&#160;world</string>
```

or

```
new TextView("Hello\u00A0world");
```

Answer (score 3):

One unique situation I ran into was adding a non-breaking space to a string resource that took `String.format` parameters.

```
<resources>
    <string name="answer_progress" formatted="false">Answered %d of %d</string>
</resources>
```

I tried to simply copy and past the non-breaking space character into the string and it was replaced with a regular old space after compiling.

Removing the *formatted="false"*, numbering the format args and using the backslash notation worked for me:

```
<resources>
    <string name="answer_progress">Answered %1$d\u00A0of\u00A0%2$d</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(your string, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(your string);
}
```

Comment: It only makes string look like HTML text. You should set a required text in `your string`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that using nbsp in a TextView

`<string name="text">Example:\u00A0</string>`

Comment: That should be \u00A0

Answer (score 1):

Strange, but in my case non of these two worked:

- `&nbsp;`
- `\u00A0`
  The `TextView` was showing them as text.

So I just inserted non-breaking space as it is: " "

Answer (score 0):

I needed `narrow no-break space` (nnbs) in my app (its smaller then regular space) but nothing worked for me.

So i made this extension to `simulate nnbs`

**For spannable**

```
fun SpannableString.transparent(symbol: String): SpannableString {
    val startIndex = indexOf(symbol)
    val endIndex = startIndex + symbol.length

    setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(android.R.color.transparent), startIndex, endIndex, 0)
    return this
}

fun SpannableString.fontSize(symbol: String, fontSize: Int): SpannableString {
    val startIndex = indexOf(symbol)
    val endIndex = startIndex + symbol.length

    setSpan(AbsoluteSizeSpan(fontSize), startIndex, endIndex, SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
    return this
}
```

**For TextView**:

```
/**
 * Font size divider for narrow no-break space
 */
const val NNBS_FONT_SIZE_DIVIDER = 3f

/**
 * Unique symbol for simulating narrow no-break space
 */
const val NNBS_SYMBOL = "$"

/**
 * For some reasons, Android not supporting narrow no-break space.
 * This extension make @param symbol transparent and decrease font size to
 * simulate narrow no-break space
 */
fun TextView.narrowNoBreakSpace(symbol: String, originalText: String) {
    val nnbsFontSize = (textSize / NNBS_FONT_SIZE_DIVIDER).roundToInt()

    text = SpannableString(originalText)
        .transparent(symbol)
        .fontSize(symbol, nnbsFontSize)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
val text = "Here is >$NNBS_SYMBOL< narrow no-break space."
textView.narrowNoBreakSpace(NNBS_SYMBOL, text)
```