# Android TextView line break

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView that contains a list of comma seperated phone numbers. i.e. (917) 234-5678, (917) 423-2312 etc

The problem is that the TextView line breaking on spaces so i get something like this:

```
|(917) 234-5678, (917) 456-8290, (917)|
|423-2313                             |
```

Is there any way to add an "invisible" character that will prevent the TextView from breaking mid-phone number, or alternately some other way of controlling where the line breaks?

UPDATE:
One other note, the strings are unknown so I can't just add line breaks in the right place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android and &nbsp; in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564794/android-and-nbsp-in-textview)

Comment: An expandable listview is a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

you could add a line break after every comma. For example:

```
String phoneNumbers = .... your numbers
phoneNumbers.replace(",", ",\n"); // this adds a line break after all commas
```

**update:**

after comment, so maybe you should remove the extra spaces that happen mid-number. Something like:

```
phoneNumbers.replace(" ", "").replace(",", ", "); // remove all the spaces and re-add one space after the comma, that way auto-line break only happens in-between numbers
```

The point is that TextView does not have any feature to change the way it breaks lines. So your solution must rely on passing a String to it that it will be more compatible with the way it handles it.

Comment: just updated the question, that would work but in my case there are actually several numbers that fit before the break happens

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @comrade for pointing out the related question. By doing this:

```
number.replace(" ", "\u00A0")
```

on each number before concatenating them with commas I was able to get the line break to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is having a TextView with constant width. Have you tried setting TV width to `wrap_content` ?

Comment: The TextView is wrap_content on the height, but it match_parent on the width. I want the text thats bigger than the view to wrap

Comment: Then increase the width of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like    `yourPhoneText.replace(") ", ")");`

[More example is here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm)

Comment: I considered this but it's sort of a hack and sort of makes the numbers look weird, I may resort to this if there's no better way.